# Date comparision using CriteriaBuilder in java

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am having current `date(date)` and `friday(fridayOfTheWeek)` and `Monday(mondayOfTheWeek)`. I want to check whether date lies between Monday and Friday including.

I tried to use predicate and get method but I am not able to implement it

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Star> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Teacher.class);
    Root<Teacher> root = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);
    Join<Teacher, B> join = root.join("department").join("team");
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(join.get("department"), "subject"));
   //criteriaQuery.where(builder.between(root.get("date")), MondayOfTheWeek(), FridayOfTheWeek());
    criteriaQuery.select(root);
    Query<Teacher> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

1st method tried this

```
criteriaQuery.where(builder.between(builder.function("week", Integer.class, root.get("date")), MondayOfTheWeek(), FridayOfTheWeek()));
```

and error I am getting on builder.between is

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method between(Expression<? extends Y>, Y, Y) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<Integer>, Date, Date). The inferred type Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Y extends Comparable<? super Y>>
```

2nd method i tried is :

```
criteriaQuery.where(builder.between(root.get("date")), MondayOfTheWeek(), FridayOfTheWeek());
```

It is giving error on between which is

```
The method between(Expression<? extends Y>, Expression<? extends Y>, Expression<? extends Y>) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>)
```

3rd method i tried is:

```
ParameterExpression<java.util.Date> parameter = builder.parameter(java.util.Date.class);
Predicate startPredicate = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(MondayOfTheWeek()), parameter);
Predicate endPredicate = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(FridayOfTheWeek()), parameter);
```

Error I am getting is:

```
The method get(SingularAttribute<? super Teacher,Y>) in the type Path<Teacher> is not applicable for the arguments (Date)
```

Comment: Can't you just do it using some method `boolean isWeekday(Date date)` (or better `boolean isWeekday(LocalDate localDate)`?

Comment: No because i am already having today's date, monday and friday date. So i have to use them only, to fetch the data.

Comment: You need to use function week only if you want to get dates between monday and friday for every(!)  week. If you want to get dates in particular week and you have already calculated monday and friday of this particular week, then just use simple between(root.get("date"), MondayOfTheWeek(), FridayOfTheWeek())

Comment: This method is also giving error. Edited the code and mentioned the error above. I am not able to understand why the error is coming.

Comment: Provide please entire source code, including class Star, MondayOfTheWeek(), FridayOfTheWeek() and creating CriteriaQuery.

Comment: Entire source code added and date is in C table which is already there.

Comment: What is C? Where is its source?  Where did Star go?

Comment: Edited. C was Star class. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1. Pure Java**

You need to make your own implementation of [FunctionExpression](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/criteria/internal/expression/function/FunctionExpression.html). Below is my class for custom "contains" function (Full-Text Search in Ms Sql Server). You need to replace "contains(%s,%s)" with something like "datepart(wk, %s) between %s and %s" and use 2 properties "Expression value" instead my one. Look for "datepart" description in your database documentation.

```
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.ParameterContainer;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.ParameterRegistry;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.Renderable;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.RenderingContext;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.LiteralExpression;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.BasicFunctionExpression;

import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Models a SQL <tt>CONTAINS</tt> expression.
 *
 * @author Steve Ebersole
 */
public class ContainsFunction extends BasicFunctionExpression<Boolean> implements Serializable {
    private final Expression<String> field;
    private final Expression<String> value;

    public ContainsFunction(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder, Expression<String> field, Expression<String> value) {
        super(criteriaBuilder, Boolean.class, "contains");
        this.field = field;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ContainsFunction(
            CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder,
            Expression<String> field,
            String value) {
        this(criteriaBuilder, field, new LiteralExpression<>(criteriaBuilder, value));
    }

    public Expression<String> getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public Expression<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void registerParameters(ParameterRegistry registry) {
        ParameterContainer.Helper.possibleParameter(getField(), registry);
        ParameterContainer.Helper.possibleParameter(getValue(), registry);
    }


    @Override
    public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        return String.format("contains(%s,%s)=true" 
                , ((Renderable) getField()).render(renderingContext)
                , ((Renderable) getValue()).render(renderingContext));
    }
}
```

Usage of this custom Expression

```
query.where(new ContainsFunction((CriteriaBuilderImpl) builder, field, value))
```

**Option 2. Java + DB**

You can use [CirtiaBuilder#function](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-) method, but it does not allow to provide wk constant into SQL datepart function. If you database has builtin analogue for datapart(wk,{date}), for example week({date}), then you can write

```
query.where(builder.between(builder.function("week", Integer.class, root.get("dateField")), first, last));
```

and it will be translate to SQL

```
week(yourTable.dateField) between ? and ?
```

If you database does not have builtin function you should creare user-defined function.

Comment: Is there any short method for this. Creating function is very lengthy task and will increase the size of the code

Comment: I added second option with less code, but it's not pure java approach.

Comment: I tried second option but i am getting error. Error and changes in code i have edited in the question above. Please check and help me out.

Comment: datepart (wk, {date}) returns integer - number of day of week. Like 1 - monday, 2 - tuesday .. 7 - sunday (or it could be 1 - sunday, 2 - monday etc, depends on your DB settings). So arguments for "between" should be integer too, but you provide dates. Thats why you get this error.

Comment: No this won't work as i am already having date in Date format and have to work on that, can't change the code as it would effect project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the basics :

```
 criteriaQuery.select(root).where(
 criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("date"), MondayOfTheWeek()),
 criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("date"), FridayOfTheWeek()));
```

Comment: If I don't know that the value is of type Date, but could be String, Integer etc? How can I cast the `root.get`? I tried `root.<clazz>get()` where clazz = `Class<?>`, but it doesn't compile.